# woocommerce add extra product product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm pretty new to woocommerce so if i'm asking something stupid....please forgive me.

At the moment I'm building a webhop. The product are toys. Some toys also have a manual which can be purchased seperatly.

On the single-product-page I can see my product and I can add it to my cart. But this is only the product itself without the manual for that product. On the same single-product-page I want that vistors can add the manual for the product to the cart also.

I played with variables, grouped etc, but it's not the same as what I want.

Can this be done easily?

Regards,

Roland

Comment: Nothing in woocommerce is easily done, sadly :\ You could try relating those two products and then display related products.

Comment: What I would have done would be to 1. Add the manual product ID as meta for the toy product. 2. On the toy product's single product page add the `[add_to_cart_url id="99"]` [shortcode](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes#section-10) with the manual's ID.